# Spring transaction Manager:cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use spring transaction in my project.I have following xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz:1521:orcl" />
        <property name="username" value="TESTSPRING" />
        <property name="password" value="TESTSPRING" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

but getting following error on server start-up

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 29; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency for `spring-tx`. Add below dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```